# change the order of the date to show the lastest above and earliest below

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am making a shopping cart past transaction.
I would like to make my items to show up based on the date, 
the latest date will appear at the top follow my the earliest.

This item now is actually from the earliest to the latest.
May I know how can I change it to latest to earliest?

```
<?php
do{
$des = $row_supermarketcart['productdes'];
$pack = $row_supermarketcart['package'];
$price = $row_supermarketcart['itemprice'];
$qty = $row_supermarketcart['qty'];
$ddate = $row_supermarketcart['ddate'];


if ($row_supermarketcart['username'] == $_SESSION['MM_Username'] )
{

            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>". $des ."</td>";
            echo "<td>". $pack. "</td>";
            echo "<td>$" .$price. "</td>";
            echo "<td>". $qty. "</td>";
            echo "<td>".$ddate."</td>";


}

else
{
     echo "<br>";
      echo "<center><b>YOU HAVE NOT MAKE ANY TRANSACTION YET</b></center>";
      echo "<br>";
      echo "<br>";

}

} while ($row_supermarketcart = mysql_fetch_assoc($supermarketcart));
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

In your SQL query use an `ORDER BY` clause to sort by date:

```
 ORDER BY `ddate` DESC
```

Not only is it faster to do in your SQL query, but you then would not have to change your PHP code.

Comment: because I didn't specify any sql query in my statement for date

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean